# Open layers and django

Tags: django, openlayers

I'm new to django and open layers but I tried to create a project using both. I search the internet and found a way to make them both work with webpack but I didn't like that so much, because of 2 things, the first is the bundling process and the second is after importing the bundled file debugging wasn't that clear. I was thinking maybe there is a way to work it out without using webpack? I tried including the node_modules/ol/dist/ol.js but didn't work for me. also, I thought maybe including all node_modules in the STATICFILES_DIRS but didn't work as well, i needed later to include each file staticly. Is there a solution to this or am I bounded to work with webpacking?
Thank you!